# Finding averages from certain lines of a text file in python

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to gather numbers from a simple text file and compute the average of those numbers. However, I need two separate averages from the text file. The text file would be in this format.

```
random string
num 1
num 2
random string
random string
num 1
num 2
random string
random string
num 1 
num 2
random string
random string
num 1
num 2
random string
```

... and so on and so forth, the pattern would always be this way.

I'd need to be able to get the average of all the num1's, then the average of all the num2's separately. The numbers would be integers. What method could I use to do this? Maybe adding them to an array or list and calculating them that way? Or is there another way?

Any guidance or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The file format is good to post, but ideally also give a sample of actual data. It's unclear whether 'num 1' is literally 'num 1', or 1 is a sample number. And if you wish to categorise across two sets of numbers, then each line should have a discriminator of some sort so we can easily pick them out. In regard to actual calculation, if you don't need to store the list of numbers for later operations, then just add them (foo += num) as you go to two separate vars, and maintain a count for each (also two separate vars), finally var1/count1 to get avg1, var2/count2 to get avg2.

Comment: Design note: vars like this can be grouped together in, say, a dataclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
text = '''random string
1
2
random string
random string
3
4
random string
random string
5
6
random string
random string
7
8
random string'''
```

You can use regular expression, and get first, and second numbers in the pairs to two different lists, then perform the remaining operations:

```py
first=[]
second=[]
for m in re.finditer(r'\n(\d+)\n(\d+)\n', text):
    first.append(int(m.group(1)))
    second.append(int(m.group(2)))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
# The values captured from the text string
>>>first, second
([1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8])
# Average of first values in the pairs
>>> (sum(first)/len(first))
4.0
# Average of second values in the pairs
>>> (sum(second)/len(second))
5.0
```

Comment: what if there was a text prior to numbers? I am not an expert in regular expression and this looks nice.

Comment: IMO, collecting the numbers in memory beats the advantage of having a file, and for large files, may not even be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

start by opening the file then read the first line. Then use a for loop and add all the numbers to a total then divide by the total amount of numbers read.

```
import os

PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

with open(PATH+r"\your_text_file.txt", "r") as file:
    total_first = 0
    total_second = 0
    cardinal = 0   # The cardinal is the number of elements in a set.

    for line in file:   # I know that there is a reccurent pattern in the text file.
        try:
            int(line)
        except ValueError:   # If the line is a string, read the next 2 lines as integers then read a third line and start over.
            cardinal += 1
            total_first += int(file.readline())
            total_second += int(file.readline())
            file.readline()

    average_first = total_first / cardinal
    average_second = total_second / cardinal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract all the numbers and then work around that.

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as file:
    s = file.read()
    nums = re.findall(r'\d', s)
    nums = [int(num) for num in nums]
    nums.sort()
    print(nums)
```

This will give you a list of all integers in your text file in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [linecache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html).

```
import linecache
line = linecache.getline(file.txt, line_number) # Note: first line is 1, not 0
```

Once you can access any line, calculating the averages is trivial.